Python list comparision
I want to look into the first dataframe and look into the second dataframe to extract the matching SKU and output a comparision dataframe that will result in matching an 1-1 relationship of what item was purchased, how much it costs and the matching SKU number associated with the respective item.
import pandas as pd

materials = {"Item No.": ['SHIRT, NIKE-345','PANTS, NIKE-345','SHOES, ADIDAS-67',
                                'SHORTS, ADIDAS-67'],
             "Price": ['34.99','45.99','79.99','39.99']}

df = pd.DataFrame(materials)

matching = {"Item SKU": ['NIKE-345','NIKE-345','ADIDAS-67','ADIDAS-67']}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(matching)

#######################
Desired output:
{"Item No.": ['SHIRT, NIKE-345','PANTS, NIKE-345','SHOES, ADIDAS-67',
                                'SHORTS, ADIDAS-67'],
             "Price": ['34.99','45.99','79.99','39.99'],
             "Item Matching SKU": ['NIKE-345','NIKE-345','ADIDAS-67','ADIDAS-67']}

I have tried the .isin method and cannot get the desired output.

In the code you posted you haven't tried the .isin method. Please post the code of what you have tried.

This question is similar to: Python pandas adding column to a dataframe based on lookup in another dataframe. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi, You can use apply method. This should help but your NIKE-345 SKU number doesn't look like something we can use to match columns in the future, please can you update your df? so we can help

Perhaps you are trying to extract the SKU info from 'Item No.' and then compare it to matching df? Alternatively, you can extract SKU from 'Item No.' itself: result = df[['Item No.', 'Price']]
result['SKU'] = df.apply(lambda x: str(x['Item No.']).split()[1], axis=1)

I have tried the .isin method Show us that code.  Otherwise we have no idea what you actually did.

Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, but there's no question here and I'm not following what you need help with exactly. It seems like you just want to concat the two dfs, but you're describing something more complicated. Please take the [tour] if you haven't already and read [ask]. You can [edit] to clarify (and like others said, please add the code you tried).

IIUC, you can use regex and capture groups with .str.extract like this:
regstr = '(' + '|'.join(df2['Item SKU'].to_numpy()) + ')'
df['Item Matching SKU'] = df['Item No.'].str.extract(regstr)
df.to_dict('list')

Output:
{'Item No.': ['SHIRT, NIKE-345',
  'PANTS, NIKE-345',
  'SHOES, ADIDAS-67',
  'SHORTS, ADIDAS-67'],
 'Price': ['34.99', '45.99', '79.99', '39.99'],
 'Item Matching SKU': ['NIKE-345', 'NIKE-345', 'ADIDAS-67', 'ADIDAS-67']}

